# Weak topology of Gaussian measures

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Let us consider a space of Dirac measures $\delta_{x}$ on a Tychonoff space $X$. I know that this space is homeomorphic to $X$. A space of Gaussian measures (weak topology) on some loсally convex space is wider than the space of Dirac measures.

My question: Is the space of Gaussian measures on locally convex space $X$ homeomorphic to $X$? I'm interested about a case of an infinite-dimensional space $X$.

Comment: This seems already false when $X=\mathbb{R}$.  For instance, I think that removing one point from the space of Gaussian measures on $\mathbb{R}$ will not disconnect it.

Comment: Or, consider a box $B = [a,b] \times [c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $c>0$, and consider the map that takes $(\mu, \sigma) \in B$ to the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with the corresponding mean and standard deviation.  It seems clear that this map is injective and continuous, so the space of Gaussian measures contains a homeomorphic copy of the unit square, which of course $\mathbb{R}$ does not.  I think a similar argument would work in any finite dimensional space.

Comment: And what about a case of an infinite dimensional space?

Comment: It may possibly be true abstractly in some cases, because there are just not that many homeomorphism types of infinite-dimensional spaces (e.g. all infinite-dimensional separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic).  But I don't think you would get a homeomorphism that was "natural" in any way, and so I'm not sure how the mere existence of a homeomorphism would be useful even if it is true.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is false in any finite and infinite dimensional spaces. But I don't know how to prove it